# relative commutant of type III1 factor

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a type III$_1$ factor and $N$ be the non-trivial ($N\neq \Bbb C 1$)semi-finite von Neumann subalgebra of $M$.

What is the type of relative commutant $N'\cap M$? Is it semi-finite?

Comment: What do you mean by *the* non-trivial semi-finite von Neumann subalgebra? There are many non-isomorphic ones.

Comment: That's what you wrote. But it's still not clear to me if you want to know if the relative commutant is semi-finite for some such $N$ or all such $N$.

Comment: I want to know whether the relative commutant is semi-finite for all such $N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are examples when the relative commutant is not semi-finite. If $B$ is a type $\mathrm{III}_1$ factor, then $M=B\overline\otimes\mathbb{B}(H)\cong B$ for any separable Hilbert space $H$. Now if you take $N=\mathbb C\otimes B(H)$, then $N$ is semi-finite with relative commutant $N^\prime\cap M=B$, which is type $\mathrm{III}_1$ and hence not semi-finite.

Comment: If $M=N\rtimes_\theta \mathbb{R}$ is the continuous decomposition of $M$, then $N^\prime\cap M=\mathbb C$ (see Takesaki II, Theorem XII.1.7).

Comment: Thanks very much！